# Excel search regex text between html tags

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to replace a html strong text in an excel doc with something else via the search function.

I tried this regex but did not succeed:

```
(?<=\<strong\>).+?(?=\<\/strong\>)
```

This is my sample text:

```
<strong>APPLE</strong>
```

That shall be my result:

```
||apple||
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Replace?

```
Replace(Replace("<strong>APPLE</strong>","<strong>","||"),"</strong>","||")
```

Comment: can i make it also "excel bold" during that?

Comment: I see... you want to make it ("||APPLE||") appear bold in excel?

Comment: Hey you can check out instr functions as well as Range.Characters(x,y).font.bold = true to achieve your goal.